# override magento url routing in my module

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, utf-8

how can i override URL routing of magento2?

there is a huge UTF8 problem on URLs

magento2 don't recognize something like `تست.html`

Anybody please help me on how can i override the routing in module so I can dig into and fix the utf8 problem of URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento use \Magento\Framework\Filter\Translit to convert any symbol in url to ascii. You can create your realization and use it for Magento.

Comment: Nice ... can u post the DI.xml part?